# How to undelete from ArcGIS versioned table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, versioning

We have a versioned table of polygons and one of our users have deleted every geometries.

With Oracle's SQL Developer, i can see the table still containing the missing data, along with its Axxxx and Dxxxx tables, representing the versioned actions (the Axxxx table stores the data added to our table and the Dxxxx the row number of the deleted data).

I understand that ArcGIS Desktop use an Oracle View that computes the added and deleted data to the table.

Is there a way to restore or undelete those polygons (and their attributes) ? Can I just empty that Dxxxx table, which contains row numbers of the deleted polygons ?

We have ArcGIS Server 10.2.2, ArcGIS Desktop 10.4 and Oracle 11.

Comment: do you have a backup?

Comment: of course, but isn't it also the purpose of a versioned table, to be able to step back from edits ?

Comment: It depends on how far your automation has prepared to accept those edits. They haven't been deleted *yet*, but they may be entangled in other edits in the same version lineage. If they're isolated, all you need to do is move the version to the start of the tree where deletion occurred. You should only hack the Dn table under direction from Tech Support.

Comment: Has the delete propagated to the default table or are you looking at the Table view?  (ex.  TableName_evw)

You say you can see the table with the missing data.  Which table?

Comment: the view `tablename_evw` has no data. the delete has not propagate to the table `tablename`, it still has all the data (332 rows)

Comment: Whatever you do don't compress the database. Are there other versions that were created before the polys were deleted? If there are then these versions might still have your data, if they haven't been reconciled. You can export the polys from these versions.